# Prove that $B$ is base for $T$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be bases for the same topology $T$ in a set $X$. Prove that the family
$B = \{U ∈ B_1 | ∃V, W ∈ B_2\ \text{s.t}\ V ⊆ U ⊆
W\}$ is also the basis for $T$

**My try.**

Let $ x \in X $, by definition of base there exists $ W \in B_2 $ such that $ x \in W $. Then, since $ W \in T $, and since $ T $ is generated by $ B_1 $, there exists an element $ U \in B_1 $ such that $ x \in U \subseteq W $. Similarly, since $ U \in T $ and $ T $ is also generated by $ B_2 $, there exists $ V \in B_2 $ such that $ x \in V \subseteq U $. And I would have it right?

**Try 2.** We have to prove that there exists $ U_0 \in B $ such that $ x \in U_0 \subseteq \mathcal {U} $. Let $ \mathcal {U} $ be an open of $ X $ and let $ x  \in \mathcal {U} $, then Given $ U_0 \in B_1 $, with $ x \in U_0 $, there exists $ V \in B_2 $ such that $ x \in V \subseteq U_0 $. On the other hand, given $ W \in B_2 $, there exists $ P \in B_1 $ such that $ y \in P \subseteq W $. It remains to prove that $ U_0 \subseteq P $. Let's reason for absurdity, and suppose that $ U_0 \not \subseteq P $, that way $ U_0 \cap P = \varnothing $, but this is absurd since the intersection of basics is a basic one.

Comment: Let $O$ be open in $T$ and $x \in O$. Now apply that $B_2$ is a base, then $B_1$, then $B_2$ again to find $U,V \in B_2$, $W \in B_1$ so that $x \in U \subseteq W \subseteq V \subseteq O$. Then $W \in B$ is as required.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the fact that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for the space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ iff

$$\forall O \in \mathcal{T}:\forall x \in O\exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq O\tag{1}$$

Then the fact that $\mathcal{B} = \{U \in \mathcal{B}_1\mid \exists V,W \in \mathcal{B}_2: V \subseteq U \subseteq W\}$ is a base for $(X,\mathcal{T})$ whenever $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ are is an immediate consequence.